# DevExpress GridControl : Adding a new row "in-control" as in Windows.Forms GridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, devexpress

When I try to add a new row by clicking the *NewItemRow* placed in bottom of the grid, it allows me to edit the cell, but when I press enter it simply doesn't add it to the list, instead takes me to the next column; **Editing properties are set to True**. When I run the *Designer*, in the Feature Browser section the Sample View allows me to add new rows as I want, but in my grid don't.

Allows me to type in the cell:
http://s28.postimg.org/3ybb5tq65/Problem.jpg

Takes me to the next column, doesn't adding what I already typed:
http://s10.postimg.org/k4cq73m5l/Problem2.jpg

Forcing me to use another Form and using code to add a new row based on text fields, what is non-convenient for the target user of my application.
In a standard DataGridView it automatically adds rows with the typed content by pressing Enter or selecting other cell.

Comment: Is the grid bound to a collection?Make sure that the column FieldName is set correctly

Comment: It's not directly bound to a collection, it will have the option to import from Excel using Office.Interop and a DataTable, or typing manually new values and then saving it to a custom database.

Comment: Are you sure?If is not bound to anything i think it does not let you add rows.

Comment: Mmm, I was thinking of editing manually the Grid, then use a DataTable element to save the "database" to a file with a custom format. I have found that in Telerik RadGrid this can be done, as in Windows.Forms standard DataGridView.

I have found a partial solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSwClk_s9rA

But it requires to use a button, i guess it will work, but I was expecting to be able to add new rows with the typed content instead of first pressing a button and then moving to select the new row and edit it. It is a light usability issue.